# Returning an object to a method in a ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to call a method that returns an object and need help as I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it is called. I am trying to get a QuoteMap object returned to the ViewController that calls it.

The method is addAndReturnQuoteMap which is as declared in the header QuoteMap.h

```
- (QuoteMap *)addAndReturnQuoteMap:(NSString *)subId withQuoteId:(NSString *)quoteId;
```

The method itself looks like this:

```
- (QuoteMap *)addAndReturnQuoteMap:(NSString *)subId withQuoteId:(NSString *)quoteId {

//FIRST GET A NEW QUOTE_MAP_ID

NSInteger newQuoteMapId = self.getNextQuoteMapId;
NSLog(@"newQuoteMapId = %d", newQuoteMapId);

// THEN TAKE THE QUOTE_MAP_ID, SUBJECT_ID AND QUOTE_ID AND INSERT INTO QUOTE_MAP TABLE

NSLog(@"subId = %@   quoteId = %@", subId, quoteId);

QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDelegate.getDBPath];    

if ([database open]) {
    [database executeUpdate:@"insert into QUOTE_MAP(quote_map_id, quote_id, subject_id) values(?, ?, ?)", 
     newQuoteMapId, subId, quoteId];

    [database close];
}

[database open];

FMResultSet *result_categories = [database executeQuery:@"select * from QUOTE where quote_id = 835"];
[result_categories next];

QuoteMap *qm = [QuoteMap alloc];
qm.quote_map_id = [result_categories stringForColumn:@"QUOTE_MAP_ID"];
qm.quote_id = [result_categories stringForColumn:@"QUOTE_ID"];
qm.subject_id = [result_categories stringForColumn:@"SUBJECT_ID"];
qm.isDirty = NO;

NSLog(@"QuoteMap inserted the quote_map_id of: %@", qm.quote_map_id);
[qm release];

return qm;

};
```

I call the method from my AddQuoteViewController here:

```
    [qm addAndReturnQuoteMap:mySubjectId withQuoteId:quote.quote_id];
```

I am sure there is something really stupid that I am doing wrong and would appreciate any direction on what that might me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `init` on your `QuoteMap`. It should be:

```
QuoteMap *qm = [[QuoteMap alloc] init];
```

There is no case where you should call a bare `+alloc` without immediately calling some form of `-init`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to init qm and not just allocate memory for it:

```
QuoteMap *qm = [[QuoteMap alloc] init];
```

And do not  release the returning object, cause it is invalid after this. Make it autorelease.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code into

```
QuoteMap *qm = [[QuoteMap alloc] init];
//your code
[qm autorelease];
return qm;
```